# We are using Magento 2.3.4 The order confirmation email is not sent

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

the order confirmation email is not sent to customer how to fix this problem....moreover the problem is entirely different,here welcome email,forget password, shipping and invoice mails are delivered

but order confirmation email only not going

please help me someone

Answer (score 1):

Got to **Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System** and check that  **Disable Email Communications** is set to No.

Now navigate to **Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails**
under **General Settings** tab, choose **Asynchronous sending** to **Disable**

Now **Enabled Order tab  to Yes**

hope this works for you